# VSCode only shows one line of Github Copilot suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I've activated github copilot and it works fine but, while typing it only shows one line of suggestion. After all of my tryings, It still shows one line of suggestion. But I want to see multi-line suggestions.

[image: One line suggestion]

Even the all solutions tab show one line of complete solutions.

[image]

Here is my user settings.json

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "diffEditor.codeLens": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.DS_Store": false,
        "**/.hg": false,
        "**/.svn": false,
        "**/CVS": false,
        "node_modules": true
    },
    "thunder-client.codeSnippetLanguage": "js-axios",
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "aws.profile": "profile:kahramanlar",
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "github.copilot.inlineSuggest.enable": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to press tab, and then to wait a couple of seconds? A new multiline suggestion should appear for the following lines. (I'm having the same "problem" with C++)

Comment: Seems to be a known problem: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/13303

Answer (score 7):

This bug currently affects all versions of vs code and is known to the developers. Since yesterday they officially announced that they are [working on the issue:](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/13303#discussioncomment-2719086)

> Hi folks, this is GH Copilot team. We hear your feedback and are actively working to address it. Dave and I will keep you folks updated on the progress. Thanks again!

Comment: seems like it got resolved!

Comment: Still happening to me

Comment: This is happening to me too

Comment: Still getting this in february 2023...

Comment: So am I. Still getting this in february 2023....

Comment: 06 April 2023 ... still happeneing... Sometimes it's answer is the question I just asked... 

Comment: I had this too and it went away with blocking public results, which is configured at the beginning. I switched it back from Allow to Blocked and now I get better results, whole functions. Before that I didn't even get code, just comments or comments with links.

Comment: Looks like this issue re-surfaced Dec 2022 and is being discussed here: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/40522#discussioncomment-4706865

Comment: Bug (if it is a bug) is still there. This is happening to me too.

Comment: Still in jan/24

Answer (score 3):

For VSCode in Mac OS changing the `n.multiline||(h.stop=["\n"]` to `n.multiline||(h.stop=["\n\n\n"]` in `/dist/extention.js` file fix the problem for me.

Or using just this single-line code from [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/40522#discussioncomment-6736514):

```
sed -i 's/\["\\n"\]/["\\n\\n\\n"]/' $(ls ~/.vscode/extensions/github.copilot-*/dist/extension.js)
```

Comment: Yes, this helped! Any ideas if this is fixed already?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem.
So shameful they can't fix this for a year now.